# Map step to linear scale more than 100 with MUI Slider

Tags: material-ui, slider

I'm using MUI slider, and I'm at a loss how to create a slider with mapping for values more than 100. Apart from creating all 180 days in the mark array and restricting the values, is there another way to do it? I was hoping to be able to set something like `step={1}` and `stepLength={100/180}` which will give the distance travelled on the line per step (signifying one day).

I have this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7iyj3?file=/demo.js) with my not-working-correctly example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had this same problem. Add

```
max={180}
```

In your

```
<Slider 
...
min={0}
max={180}
...
/>
```

Then change the values under your labels inside of

```
const Marks = [...];
```

To get your desired output!

If you want to add a side button to increment by a certain amount, MUI also has an [input field](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/) option.